# Unix create and use variables inside expect script

Tags: unix, awk, ssh, expect, csh

In my attempts to automatize access to a remote computer,
I am trying to create and use variables inside an expect script.

I am trying to do the following:

```
#!/bin/csh -f
/user/bin/expect<<EOF_EXPECT
set USER     [lindex $USER 0]
set HOST     [lindex $HOST 0]
set PASSWD   [lindex $PASSWD 0]
set timeout 1
spawn ssh $USER@$HOST
expect "assword:"
send "$PASSWRD\r"
expect ">"
set list_ids (`ps -ef | grep gedit | awk '{ print $2 }'`)
expect ">"
for id in ($list_ids)
    send "echo $id\r"
end
send "exit\r"
EOF_EXPECT
```

Several challenges with this code:

1. The `ps | grep | awk` line does not act as in the shell. It does not extract only the `pid` using the `awk` command. Instead, it takes the whole line.
2. The variable `$list_ids` is unrecognized although I set it using what I thought is variable setting inside expect script.
3. Lastly, how to do the `for` loop so that `$id` and `$id_list` will be recognized?

I am using csh. `$env(list_ids)` does not work for me, `$env` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

1. Both shell and `tcl` variables are marked with `$`. The contents of your here document are being expanded by your shell. You don't want that. `csh` doesn't have a value for `$2` so expands it to the empty string and the awk command ends up becoming `ps -ef | grep gedit | awk '{ print }'`. Which is why you get the entire lines in the output.

   You have your contexts confused here a bit. You need to escape the `$` from the external `csh` if you want it to make it through to the embedded awk command. (Which is horrible but apparently the case for `csh`.)

   In general you need to not try to merge csh and tcl commands/etc. like this it will greatly help you understand what is happening.
2. What do you mean "unrecognized"? Are you getting any other errors (like from the `set` command)?
3. I think you are looking for [`foreach`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1018):

   ```
   $ tclsh
   % foreach a [list 1 2 3 4] b [list 5 6 7 8] c [list a b c d] d [list w x y z]
       puts "$a $b $c $d"
   }
   1 5 a w
   2 6 b x
   3 7 c y
   4 8 d z
   %
   ```

`$env(list_ids)` is a `tcl` variable. That `csh` doesn't know anything about it is unrelated to anything (well other than the problem in point one above so escape it). If you export `list_ids` in the `csh` session that runs the `tcl` script then `$env(list_ids)` should work in the `expect` script.

You don't want the `()` around the value in the `set` command either I don't think. They are literal there I believe. If you are trying to create a tcl list there from the (shell expanded) output from that `ps` pipeline then you need:

```
set list_ids [list `ps ....`]
```

But as I said before you don't really want to be mixing contexts like that.

If you can use a non-`csh` shell that would likely help here also as `csh` is just generally not good at all.

Also, not embedding an expect script inside a csh script would help if you can just write an expect script as the script file directly.

Comment: Thank you! the `[list ....]` really helped. I had to use `csh`, it is a part of a bigger script. `foreach` was not recognized under my `expect` script so I used `while` in the end. Posted my answer down below.

Answer (score 0):

Reading here helped me a lot: 
http://antirez.com/articoli/tclmisunderstood.html

The following lines do the trick, and answer all questions:

```
set list_ids [list {`ps -ef | grep gedit | awk '{print \$2 }'}]
set i 0
while {[lindex \$list_ids \$i] > 0} {
  puts [lindex \$list_ids \$i]
  set i [expr \$i + 1]
}
```